# Difference between write and update in odoo11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

What is the difference between **write and update** method in **odoo11** because when i use write it work first time only then it not work.

Comment: read the docs to know

Comment: Please go through this link https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For simple fields

- [`write({'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'})`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write)

should give you a single update statement in the database, and

- `update({'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'})`

iterates over the fields and sets each one separately giving you multiple update statements in the database.